# Variadic template function composition

Tags: c++, c++11, recursion, variadic-templates, c++14

Hoping the stackoverflow community can help me with this problem. I would like to have something like the following compile

```
template <typename A>  
void VARIADIC_TEMPLATE_FUNCTION(A* tptr)
{   
    //Do nothing
}   

template <typename A, typename B, typename... C>
void VARIADIC_TEMPLATE_FUNCTION(A* tptr)
{   
    // Do stuff here with typename B and tptr (not included)
    VARIADIC_TEMPLATE_FUNCTION<A,C...>(tptr);
}
```

clearly this doesn't work, the signatures of the two functions conflict.

I have been attempting to fix this by passing some variadic arguments as well, but nothing seems to work. I'm not against passing "fake" variables - but prefer not to.

The caller would do something like (for example):

```
ClassP* ptr;
VARIADIC_TEMPLATE_FUNCTION<ClassP, ClassA, ClassB, ClassC, ClassD>(ptr);
```

Comment: And what's the problem with what you have right now? For the function call you've shown, the second overload should be called (recursively) 4 times, and then the first overload once.

Comment: It compiles and runs flawlessly

Comment: Maybe you have to enable the C++11 support. What compiler are you using?

Comment: Voting to close, as the OP did not include the *specific problem* that occurred (other than 'clearly this doesn't work').

Comment: Ugh, I don't understand why I was having trouble with this before - it does work perfectly. I should stop drinking beer before midday.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because my problem is not a problem.

Answer (score 2):

The code you have compiles perfectly fine for me, so I'm not entirely sure what the question is. But if what you want to express is performing some operation for each type in a pack, I like the following approach:

```
template <typename B, typename A>
void impl(A* tptr) {
    // Do stuff here with typename B and tptr (not included)           
}

template <typename A, typename... Ts>
void VARIADIC_TEMPLATE_FUNCTION(A* tptr) {
    int unused[] = {0, (impl<Ts>(a), 0)... };
    (void)unused;
}
```

Makes the intent clearer, once you get past the weird `int` array of `0`s we're introducing.

Comment: now that seems like real hack, but pretty good one

Comment: Just yesterday I [avoided recursion](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29901074/2073257), just to fail today. #-P Have an upvote for avoiding it!

Comment: @DanielFrey say it again: never recurse, say it again: never recurse,

Comment: @DanielFrey Don't you use the same trick in your answer there with `swallow`?

Comment: @Barry Yep. It's not that I don't know, it just so easy to forget to apply it. I guess it's a historical accident that whenever variadic templates are used, the first reflex is to use recursion. Bad habits are hard to overcome...

Answer (score 0):

Turn it into a `struct` which you can specialize:

```
template<typename...> struct IMPL;

template <typename A>
struct IMPL<A>
{
    static void apply(A* tptr)
    {   
        //Do nothing
    }   
};

template <typename A, typename B, typename... C>
struct IMPL<A,B,C...>
{
    static void apply(A* tptr)
    {   
        // Do stuff here with typename B and tptr (not included)
        IMPL<A,C...>::apply(tptr);
    }   
};

template <typename A, typename... Ts>
void VARIADIC_TEMPLATE_FUNCTION(A* tptr)
{
    IMPL<A,Ts...>::apply(tptr);
}
```

Comment: Edit: it wont because static, of course.... But still, it seems to work fine for Paolo M

Comment: @Creris I don't know what compiler OP is using and what exact problem it has, the above is usually easier for compilers to handle so maybe it helps. I'm not claiming it should be necessary. :)